# How to best parse database urls to fetch depending on html file?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, fetch-api

I have a small project consisting of my frontend, my backend spring boot project using JPA, and my MySQL database.

In the different html files I fetch and display different entities, e.g. customers, activities, and employees. So, each html file has their own entity to display. I have a js file for fetching from db. How do I best manage the different endpoints?

When I'm on the "acitivities" html site and want to fetch activities, how do I best parse that endpoint to fetch, and when I'm on a site for vieweing employees, I parse the employee endpoint?

I'm not sure how to best change endpoint depending on what entities to fetch. Should js get the endpoint from html or should I switch in js and parse the endpoint that fits the html site?

For now I just have the endpoint hardcoded:

```
const urlActivity = "http://localhost:8080/activities"
let activityList = []
const ddSelectActivity = document.getElementById("ddSelectActivity")

window.addEventListener("load", loadActivity)

async function loadActivity(){
    activityList = await fetchAny(urlActivity);
    console.log(activityList)
    activityList.forEach(fillActivityDropDown)
 }
function fetchAny(url) {
    console.log(url)
    return fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()) }
```

Comment: What is ddSelectActivity? Does it hold the selected endpoint?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ddSelectivity is the html id of a select element. the fillActivityDropDown function fills that dropdown. urlActivity has the endpoint.